# unable to query for a specific "user subscription" in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating a django ecommerce site; This site "sells" digital items. I'm unable to fetch a specific " user subscription", meaning a user has bought this digital item and I want to display it in a template.
in this case I'm interested in displaying the "plan_name" (from subscription model), "created_date" and "expiry_date" in the template **for a specific user** but somehow I'm unable to.
Hereunder the code:

models.py

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Subscription Plan Name")    
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Subscription Plan Description")   
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Subscription Plan Price")   
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Subscription Plan Start Date")
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Subscription Plan End Date")   
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)         

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Subscription"
        verbose_name_plural = "Subscriptions"       

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Subscription"""

        return " Subscription type: {}, Description: {}, Price: {}, Is active: {}".format(
                self.plan_name,
                self.description,
                self.price,
                self.active
            )

class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name= 'tosubscriptions', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey("Subscription", related_name = 'tosubscriptions',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created Date")
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Expiry Date")
    is_canceled = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is Canceled")
    cancel_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User Subscription"
        verbose_name_plural = "User Subscriptions"

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of UserSubscription"""

        return "PK: [{}] Subscription of: {}, Subscription type: {}, Expiring the: {}".format(
                str(self.pk),
                str(self.user),
                str(self.subscription),
                str(self.expiry_date)
            )
```

views.py

```
class MyProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'myprofile.html'
    model = UserSubscription

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['usersubscription'] = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
My Profile
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Username: {{user.username}}</p>
<p>First Name: {{user.first_name}}</p>
<p>Last Name: {{user.last_name}}</p>
<p>Birth Date: {{user.userprofile.birth_date}}</p>
<p>Email: {{user.email}}</p>
<p>Language: {{user.userprofile.language}}</p>
<p>Address: {{user.userprofile.address}}</p>
<p>Postal Code: {{user.userprofile.postal_code}}</p>
<p>Country: {{user.userprofile.country}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'updatemyprofile' %}">Update My Profile</a>
<hr>
<p>My Current Plan:{{usersubscription.subscription.plan_name}}</p>
<p>Start Date: {{usersubscription.created_date}}</p>
<p>End Date: {{usersubscription.expiry_date}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Renew my Subscription</a>
<hr>
<p>My Bills:</p>
<p>Bill 1: {{usersubscription.subscription.price}} €</p>
{% endblock  %}
```

Result:

Username: foo

First Name: foo

Last Name: bar

Birth Date: Feb. 2, 2020

Email: foo@bar.com

Language: EN

Address: foobar avenue

Postal Code: 1000

Country: US

Update My Profile

**My Current Plan:**

**Start Date:**

**End Date:**

Renew my Subscription

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a queryset no a single `UserSubscription`. Try

```
 UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first()
```

it will take only the first subscription, or change the logic of how you get the particular subscription for your purpose.

Comment: That did it Sergey. In fact I wanted to display the last subscripion so used.last(). Thanks a lot!